# the marquee tag in html works well for horizontal direction but not for vertical direction

Tags: html, marquee

The marquee tag works for horizontal direction perfectly but when I set its direction to up or down, what happens is that the picture scrolls only half way down the screen/page. I want it to scroll all the way till the bottom of the page but it does not. why?

```
    <html>
        <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="down">
           <img src="Blue Hills.jpg" />
           <img src="Water lilies.jpg" />
           <img src="Sunset.jpg" />
        </marquee>

   </html>
```

Comment: Can you please post the relative code that you 've tried?

Comment: From the W3: "No, really. don't use it." (http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/marquee)

Comment: so I should try CSS or Javascript,is it? Thank u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `marquee` attribute  `height="100%"` should do the trick.

Please note that the height of the `marquee` is relative to the container inside the `marquee` resides. In your case that you don't have any containers the `marquee` will occupy the whole screen

`marquee` tag is actually an old-styled HTML technique that AFAIK is not used in modern web-sites.

Nevertheless, if you really want such an animation you should consider reviewing [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) alternatives such as [jScroller](http://jscroller.markusbordihn.de/)

Comment: what if i did use a container?

Comment: Not only is marquee "old-style" but it was never a part of the HTML spec. It's invalid and shouldn't be used if only for aesthetic reasons alone.